# Which mantises explode?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I've noticed that when I loot mantis legs off of some mantises they explode. Others (most in the wasteland, in fact) don't. Which mantises explode upon you looting their legs, and why is it different?

## UPDATE

Going through Vault 22 again, this time as a goody-two-shoes for the NCR. What I've found is that not only do the Vault 22 mantises explode upon me looting their legs, but I also seem to get 20XP each time I do so. I still have not gotten a mantis to explode after looting it anywhere but Vault 22, so I'm beginning to think this is just a Vault 22 thing. Can anyone confirm or deny?

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is pretty clearly not what John was looking for, but I'm going to leave it up, because it's a good excuse to post Pushy.gif.**

I'm pretty sure this is just a randomly generated death animation from good ol' Havok., designed to infuriate you and ruin your loot.

See also: Pushy.gif
[image]

Comment: It's post-death, though: It happens after looting. You take their legs, *then* they explode. It's pretty consistent around Vault 22, but otherwise it seems semi-random. Never happens early-game though.

Comment: Oh *that*. I've had that happen in Goodsprings Schoolhouse too. So I'd dispute 'never happens early game'.

Comment: You've had it happen in Goodsprings Schoolhouse? I haven't, and I'm on my third run-through ... Wonder if it's a random thing then ...

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I noticed that issue too, and I believe (but have not gone back to kill enough mantises in other areas to confirm), that the issue is how many legs they have on the corpse --</strike>

<strike>If you're only removing one leg, no explosion ... if you're removing two, then you get the spray of whatever it is.</strike>

**update** : my theory was wrong, but I'm not deleting this, so there's a record that this is *not* the correct answer.

Comment: I've definitely removed 2, and even 3, without explosions, but thank you anyway. No downvote, just still looking for the answer. :/ Beginning to think it's something specific to the vault mantises ...

Comment: @John : I went through Vault 11 yesterday, and noticed that some with one leg on them were exploding ... so it's we've disproved my theory from both sides.